# Passing an id to a PHP script using jQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is the code that the user have a participation with.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    include 'connection.php';

    $sql="SELECT * FROM blog";

    $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        if(!$result)
            {
                $output='Error fetching students:'.mysqli_error($link);
            }
?>

<div id="table">
<table border='1' cellpadding='10' id="table">

    <tr>
        <td><b>Title<b></td>
        <td><b>Edit<b></td>
        <td><b>Delete<b></td>
    </tr>

    <?php 


        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<tr class="record">';
                echo '<td><a href="#" id="'.$row['articleid'].'" class="title">'.$row['articletitle'] .'</a>';
                echo '<td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>';
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['articleid']."'></td>";  
                echo '<td><div align="center"><a href="" id="'.$row['articleid'].'" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">Delete</a></div></td>';
                echo "</tr>\n";


            }

    echo '<form method="post" id="myForm" action="postview.php">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="myID">';
    echo '</form>';

?>

</table>
<button id="addrecord">Add New Post</button>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#addrecord").click(function(){
        $("#table").load("addpost.php");
        $("#addrecord").hide();
        });//add

$(".delbutton").click(function(){

//Save the link in a variable called element
    var element = $(this);

//Find the id of the link that was clicked
    var del_id = element.attr("id");

//Built a url to send
    var info = 'id=' + del_id;
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?"))
        {

            $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "delete.php",
                        data: info,
                        success: function(){}
                    });//ajax

            $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
            .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

        }

return false;

});//delete

$(".title").click(function(){
    $('[name=myID]').val($(this).attr('id'));
    $('#myForm').submit();
});//view

$(".edit").click(function(){
    var data=$("#tryform").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "editpost.php",    
                        data: data
                        }).done(function( msg ) {
                        $("#table").html(msg);
                    });//ajax


});//delete

});


</script>



</body>
</html>
```

and this the PHP script that the code above redirect to.

```
<?php 

include 'connection.php';
$id=$_GET['id'];
echo $id;
$sql="SELECT * FROM blog WHERE articleid='$id'";

$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
echo "<table>";

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['articletitle'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><img src='image.php?id=$row[articleid]' width='200' height='200' /><br/></td>";
echo "<td>".$row['articlemore'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";



echo "</table>";
//echo "</div>";
?>
```

I'm having this kind of error:

Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\ckeditor\samples\postview.php on line 4

Comment: Probably there is no id parameter present in your url? WHat happens when you echo $row['articleid']?

Comment: How do i do that if I want my website to not get redirected to the postview.php

Comment: Remove the action from `echo '<form method="post" id="myForm" action="postview.php">';`

Comment: BTW: Unescaped `$` symbol in `'image.php?id=$row[articleid]'`, or make proper use: `'image.php?id=" . $row['articleid'] . "'`

Answer (score 0):

That isnt an error, but a notice, which is lowlevel It simple means `$_GET['id']` doesnt hav a value

```
echo $example['something']; // will give undefined index notice
$example['something'] = 'abc';
echo $example['something']; // No notices
```

Your website should be `domain.ext/?id=123`, if not, this notice will show.

Comment: I'm sure it has a value before sending it to the PHP script, but it somehow get lost in the middle of the transaction because as you can see in my code(postview.php) I'd echoed the id and I don't get any result.

Comment: Also he is using a from, so there are no visible url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if argument "id" is passed to the php script first

```
<?php 

include 'connection.php';
if( (isset($_GET['id'])) && ($_GET['id'] != '') ){ //check if the argument "id" is passed to the script
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    echo $id;
    $sql="SELECT * FROM blog WHERE articleid='$id'";

    $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    echo "<table>";

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['articletitle'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><img src='image.php?id=$row[articleid]' width='200' height='200' /><br/></td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['articlemore'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";



    echo "</table>";
//echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer to your question, but probably a good suggestion to make your code a lot cleaner- try using [PHP Alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and moving in and out of PHP to make your HTML clean.

```
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)):?>
                <tr class="record">';
                    <td><a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['articleid'];?>" class="title"><?php echo $row['articletitle'];?></a>
                    <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['articleid'];?>'></td>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">
                            <a href="" id="<?php echo $row['articleid'];?>" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<?php endwhile;?>

<form method="post" id="myForm" action="postview.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="myID">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM blog WHERE articleid='".$id."'";
```

try this line

Comment: `$id = "1 OR 1=1; DROP TABLE blog; --"`

Comment: Only works if the connection supports multiple queries in one call

Comment: @Martijn you could still pass the first part and get a whole bunch of results that you shouldn't.

Comment: `mysql_query` does not support multiple statements. `mysqli` does: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php